# Understanding raiden cipher: Undefined behaviour in code?

Tags: c, encryption, undefined-behavior

Looking at the raiden cipher and not sure I understand the code:

```
void raiden(unsigned long *in,unsigned long *res,unsigned long *key)
{ 
  unsigned long b0=in[0],b1=in[1],i,k[4]={key[0],key[1],key[2],key[3]},sk;
  for(i=0; i< 16; i++)
  {
    sk=k[i%4]=((k[0]+k[1])+((k[2]-k[3])ˆ(k[0]<<k[2])));
    b0 += ((sk+b1)<<9)ˆ((sk-b1)ˆ((sk+b1)>>14));
    b1 += ((sk+b0)<<9)ˆ((sk-b0)ˆ((sk+b0)>>14));
  }
  res[0]=b0;
  res[1]=b1;
}
```

Considering 'key' (and thus 'k') are 32-bit values, I'd expect that k[2] is typically going to be much larger than 31, so the code above is undefined, or at least compiler-implementation defined?

I've tried to find more technical documentation on the cipher, which seems to claim that its a rotate, but in that case, why is it using a shift?

Or is this just a half-assed algorithm and I shouldn't even be looking at it? [I'm thinking of encrypting real data with it]

Comment: Why would anybody know what the 'raiden' cipher is? Perhaps you can include a link with some additional info and context. Where did your code snippet come from?

Comment: The code above is defined.  With unsigned math, the result is defined to wrap.  (modulo ULONG_MAX+1)

Comment: @GregS Maybe http://www.google.com/url?url=http://raiden-cipher.sourceforge.net/&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=C0dhVOO7IseoyASG0YL4DA&ved=0CBQQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNH8CU9Q2VIBfAh6asj3GKQQOmBC_Q

Comment: 1) "its a rotate, ... why is it using a shift " C does not have rotate, so rotates are done with a composite of shifts. 2) Suggest using `uint32_t`  as unsigned long bit length may be 32, 64, etc.

Comment: @chux: the expression `(k[0]<<k[2])` is the problem. The C standard states: "If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @GregS Yes, I agree. a shift >= width is not defined behavior.  (of course negative does not apply here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you're interested in this particular cipher, it doesn't seem to have been given much development. It does appear, from the little fragmentary information available, that key[0] through key[3] are meant to be treated as 32-bit quantities. If so, the expression `(k[0]<<k[2])` is undefined, as clearly indicated by the following clause in the C standard:

"If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined."

In fact, over the years, I have seen two different behaviors for shift amounts that are "greater than or equal to the width" of the left operand.

1. The result is zero.
2. The right operand is reduced mod the width of the left operand and the shift occurs by this reduced amount.

It really is non-portable and should be considered a bug. Most likely the authors intended behavior #2. The comments of @chux suggesting using uint32_t instead of unsigned long are also on point.

Comment: If #2 is the intent, then the code could be fixed by doing `k[0] << (k[2] % 32)`, assuming it is also changed to use `uint32_t` as fixed width type.

Comment: Personally, I'd prefer (k[2] & 31) instead of doing a modulo. It does seem that the required effect is no.2, and the sample code is executed on intel hardware, which normally does this at the assembly level (ie, SHL EAX, 0x21 is a valid command but would be executed as SHL EAX, 1)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Raiden is an OK algorithm with no known pitfalls but it is not really tested and not standardized. It works very similar to the rest of its class of ciphers and it  should be on par with them but it is hard to know for sure. I used it a couple of times in some non-critical applications where it was really nice to have at least some data authenticity guarantee but with no real requirements for it.

The only bad thing with the algorithm is that its recommended implementation is only provided in C and it uses bitwise shift with overflow operations that can work differently depending on the compiler (different versions of GCC, IAR, Keil, ...), on the platform (GCC for x86 and ARM give similar assembly instructions but results of their execution on real hardware are different) and on the programming language of choice (C, Java, D and C++ implementations can work differently) so different devices and programs have a high chance of ending up with different opinions on what the results of the functions should be.

To overcome this issue I have modified the original code a little bit to make it platform independent while retaining the overall idea and hopefully most of the original performance and other characteristics. Here it is with a simple MAC implementation included. This is not a perfect solution and the code looks a bit ugly but it works fine and it gives same results on a all the platform I have tested so far and it should be a little easier to understand than the original one as well.

Enjoy! If you still need it of course.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>     // memcpy, memset and the others are defined here

// Platform-independent cyclic shifts. Rewrite as functions when needed.
#define BitsCount( val ) ( sizeof( val ) * CHAR_BIT )
#define Shift( val, steps ) ( steps % BitsCount( val ) )
#define ROL( val, steps ) ( ( val << Shift( val, steps ) ) | ( val >> ( BitsCount( val ) - Shift( val, steps ) ) ) )
#define ROR( val, steps ) ( ( val >> Shift( val, steps ) ) | ( val << ( BitsCount( val ) - Shift( val, steps ) ) ) )

void RaidenEncoder(const uint32_t key[4], const uint32_t data[2], uint32_t result[2])
{
    uint32_t k[4];
    uint32_t b0 = data[0], b1 = data[1];
    register int8_t i;
    k[0]=key[0]; k[1]=key[1]; k[2]=key[2]; k[3]=key[3];
    for (i=0; i<16; i++) {
        register uint32_t sk;
        sk = k[i%4] = ((k[0]+k[1])+((k[2]+k[3])^ROL(k[0],k[2])));
        b0 += ((sk+b1)<<9) ^ ((sk-b1)^((sk+b1)>>14));
        b1 += ((sk+b0)<<9) ^ ((sk-b0)^((sk+b0)>>14));
    }
    result[0] = b0;
    result[1] = b1;
}

void RaidenDecoder(const uint32_t key[4], const uint32_t data[2], uint32_t result[2])
{
    register uint32_t b0 = data[0], b1 = data[1];
    register int8_t i;
    uint32_t k[4];
    uint32_t subkeys[16];
    k[0]=key[0]; k[1]=key[1]; k[2]=key[2]; k[3]=key[3];
    //Prepare subkeys
    for(i=0; i<16; i++) {
        k[i%4]=((k[0]+k[1])+((k[2]+k[3])^ROL(k[0],k[2])));
        subkeys[i]=k[i%4];
    }
    for(i=15; i>=0; i--) {
        //Process is applied in the inverse order
        b1 -= ((subkeys[i]+b0)<<9)^((subkeys[i]-b0)^((subkeys[i]+b0)>>14));
        b0 -= ((subkeys[i]+b1)<<9)^((subkeys[i]-b1)^((subkeys[i]+b1)>>14));
    }
    result[0]=b0;
    result[1]=b1;
}

// Message authentication code checking function (64-bit digests and 128-bit keys are used).
bool CheckRaidenMAC(const uint32_t key[4], const uint32_t mac[2], uint8_t* data, const uint32_t length)
{
    register uint32_t i;
    uint32_t stage_result[2] = {0,0}; // We use fixed all-zero init vector
    uint32_t encoder_input[2] = {0,0};
    uint8_t remainder_length = length%8;
    
    // Process data length information as the first stage
    encoder_input[0] = length;
    RaidenEncoder(key, encoder_input, stage_result);
    // Calculate the MAC
    for (i=0;i<length;i+=8) {
        encoder_input[0] = stage_result[0] ^ *((uint32_t*)&data[i]);
        encoder_input[1] = stage_result[1] ^ *((uint32_t*)&data[i+1]);
        RaidenEncoder(key, encoder_input, stage_result);
    }
    // Check if we need to add padding to calculate the final stage
    if (remainder_length) {
        // Load the data remainder
        memcpy(&encoder_input[0], &data[length-remainder_length], remainder_length);
        // Put in zero padding
        memset(&encoder_input[remainder_length], 0, 8-remainder_length);
        // Process the last stage
        encoder_input[0] ^= stage_result[0];
        encoder_input[1] ^= stage_result[1];
        RaidenEncoder(key, encoder_input, stage_result);
    }
    // Check if our digest matches the provided one
    return ((mac[0] == stage_result[0]) && (mac[1] == stage_result[1]));
}
```

The implementation of `void GetRaidenMAC(const uint32_t key[4], uint32_t* mac, uint8_t* data, const uint32_t length)` should be straightforward to get from the code above if you need it.

Also be aware that Raiden is a block cipher so it is designed to independently process fixed blocks of 128 bit data. If you need to encrypt different or variable amounts of data then it is also up to you to write another function that would split your data into 16-byte chunks and feed the cipher function with the separate data blocks one by one (probably while also XOR-ing them with the previous cipher results) and to add zero padding to the last block when needed. But then it will be a new stream cipher derived from the Raiden block cipher and its perfonance will vary depending on your particular implementation. There are many ways to write such a function.